# how to extract a range of index from a list

Tags: python

```
mylist1=[11,4,5,6,8,6,3]

for i in mylist1:
    a=list(range(i))
    print(a)
    print (a[-2:2])
```

I know (a[-2:2]) is wrong but I can do something with a[0:4]
I want the result to be:

the input lists of lists here:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2]
```

to be:

```
    [ 9, 10, 0, 1]
    [2, 3, 0, 1]
    [3, 4, 0, 1, ]
    [4, 5, 0, 1 ]
    [6, 7, 0, 1,]
    [4, 5, 0, 1, ]
    [1, 2, 0, 1]
```

for instance i think of a way like:

```
[a[-2],a[-1],a[0],a[1],a[2]]
```

But it's very clumpsy.
Is there any clean way of doing this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? As I guess you want elements in cyclic fashion use modulus or do if else and for -ve left value do arr[-leftval:]+ arr[:rightVal]

Comment: Thanks!  arr[-leftval:]+ arr[:rightVal] 
this is actually the best answer. so bad you leave it as comment!

Comment: Haha... Help is important not reputation/points/badges☺️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to do:

```
mylist1 = [11, 4, 5, 6, 8, 6, 3]

for i in mylist1:
    a = list(range(i))
    print(a[-2:] + a[:2])
```

**Output**

```
[9, 10, 0, 1]
[2, 3, 0, 1]
[3, 4, 0, 1]
[4, 5, 0, 1]
[6, 7, 0, 1]
[4, 5, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for ln in range(1, len(list1)):
    list2 = [list1[n] for n in range(-ln, ln)] #magic line
    print(list2)
```

or you could also try this instead of the magic line:

```
list2 = list1[ln:] + list1[:ln]
```

Where `ln` is the number of elements you want from the end and the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use list comprehension

```
mylist1 = [11,4,5,6,8,6,3]

# [range(i) for i in mylist1] creates an array of ranges based on mylist
# [a[j] for j in range(-2,2)] for a in ... selects elements
#     a[-2],a[-1],a[0],a[1]  if you need a[2] then
#     change range(-2,2) to range(-2,3)
mylist2 = [[a[j] for j in range(-2,2)] for a in [range(i) for i in mylist1]]
```